# Question about complex $\log z$ (In context of the Residue Theorem)

Tags: complex-analysis

Im reading about evaluation definite (real) integrals by using the Residue Theorem.

More specifically, Im reading about evaluation of integrals of the form $ \intop_{0}^{\infty}\frac{P\left(x\right)}{Q\left(x\right)}dx $ where $P,Q $ are polynomials, $ Q $ have no zeroes in the real positive line, and the degree of $ Q $ is greater than the degree of $ P $ at least by 2.

Now, during the explanations the author used a definition of an analytic branch of the log, and I dont really understand where one of the lines comes from. The book is "Complex Analysis" by Joseph Bak Donald J.Newman.

This is the proof for the formula of evaluating the integrals with the Residue Theorem:

[image]

[image]

What I dont get is the marked line. Why do we add $2\pi\cdot i$ to the log? I suppose that it's coming from the phase differences, but I'd really appreciate an explanation of how the log was defined here and why exactly do we add the extra $ 2\pi i$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The complex $\log$ function is multi-valued and for many purposes we must choose a branch. In general, $\log z = \log |z| + i \theta$, where $\theta$ is the argument of of $z$. In this case, the author is just saying that $\theta \in (0, 2\pi)$, excluding the real positive axis. With this choice of branch, points slightly below the positive real axis have argument $\theta \approx 2 \pi$, while points slightly above the positive real axis will have argument $\theta \approx 0$,.

Another popular choice is to take $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi)$, which excludes the negative part of the real axis.

Comment: Correct, but more care is needed. If we go along $l_2$ from $\sqrt{N^2-\epsilon^2} - i\epsilon$ to $-i\epsilon$, the argument $\theta$ of $\log z$ always goes a from value close to $2\pi$ to $3\pi/2$. One must carefully argue why the values close to $3\pi/2$ can be neglected in the limit. The same problem occurs for $l_1$. Here $\theta$  goes from a value close to $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sure, you are correct, I was just trying to address the most immediate doubt in the OP.

Comment: How can you see that a choice of $ \theta \in (0,2\pi) $ means "excluding the real positive axis and a choice of $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi ) $ is excluding the negative real axis? I cant really see the connection here.  Also, why our choice for the argument means that the argument of complex number just above the positive real axis is $0 $ and below would be $2\pi $? How can I prove it in a formal way?

Comment: @FreeZe $\theta=0$ or $\theta =2\pi$ represents the real positive axis... If you don't let $\theta$ take these values you cannot represent real positive numbers. Just draw a point a little below the real positive axis and try to see what would be the argument, you'll see it's close to $2\pi$.